# calculate the loss to shop owner

Tags: arithmetic

A customer purchases clothes  worth **200 Rupees** from a shop. customer gives **1000 Rupee** note. Since shop owner does not have change, he collects change **(100 * 10 notes)** from the neighbor shop and gives **800 rupees** back to the customer.

After few hours neighbor shop keeper tells the shop owner that **1000 rupee note is fake** and collects his 1000 rupees.

So now **calculate the total loss** to the shop owner.

Assume that Shop owner is selling clothes without any profit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Customer gives fake 1000 note: 0
He collects 1000 from neighbour: 1000
Gives 800 back to customer: 200
Gives 1000 to neighbour: -800

End loss is 800 rupees and the clothes.

Comment: @VinayakKini No problem :D